# What does "schwallt' means?

Tags: verb

Source:
http://www.schreiber-netzwerk.eu/de/2/Geschichten/10/Sehnsucht/22436/Via-Milano,-Cagliari/

> Vernehmlich gähnend öffnet sich hier und da ein Rolltor, hervor
>   **schwallt** die Kühle der Nacht, sich entgegen zu dehnen dem, was ein
>   heißer Tag zu werden gedenkt - wieder einer in einer flimmernden
>   Kette.

I already looked up for it in cactus2000.de but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich antworte auf Deutsch, weil ich bei der Lektüre eines Textes wie dem geposteten wohl doch schon einige Grundkenntnisse der deutschen Sprache voraussetzen kann, und weil ich mich auf Deutsch besser ausdrücken kann.

---

### der Schwall (Substantiv)

Das Substantiv »Schwall« würde ich mit »gush«, »surge« oder »flood« übersetzen. Wenn im Hochsommer ein Schwall heißer Luft durch ein unmittelbar zuvor geöffnetes Fenster ins Zimmer strömt, dann heißt das, dass es vorher im Zimmer angenehm kühl war, und durch das geöffnete Fenster kommt plötzlich eine Menge heißer Luft herein. Das passiert auch dann, wenn draußen gar kein Wind weht.

Ebenso kann auch an einem kühlen Morgen durch das Öffnen einer Tür oder eines Fensters ein Schwall kühler Luft in den soeben geöffneten Raum eindringen.

Der Schwall ist nicht nur auf kalte oder heiße Luft beschränkt. An Bord eines Schiffes kann man bei starkem Seegang von einem Schwall Wasser getroffen werden, und wer sich eine lange Rede anhören muss, über den ergießt sich ein unaufhörlicher Wort-Schwall.

Siehe:
http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schwall

---

### schwellen (Verb)

Das Wort »Schwall« ist übrigens abgeleitet vom Verb »schwellen« (anwachsen) (englisch: »to swell«), von dem auch die Schwellung und das Geschwulst abstammen. Das Partizip II von »schwellen« ist »geschwollen« (english: »swollen«)

Wenn sich ein Schwall über etwas ergießt, und man das mit Hilfe eines Verbs ausdrücken will, dann ist »schwellen« aber die falsche Wahl, denn »schwellen« bedeutet das Anwachsen von etwas, nicht das Ergießen über etwas.

---

### schwallen (Verb)

Die richtige Wahl wäre »schwallen«. Doch Vorsicht! Dieses Verb ist nicht Bestandteil der Alltagssprache. Man findet es eigentlich nur im literarischen Kontext, also in Gedichten oder anderen Texten, die eine etwas abgehobene Kunst-Sprache verwenden. Das Wort »schwallt«, auf das du gestoßen bist, ist eine deklinierte Form von »schwallen« (Präsens, dritte Person singular)

Comment: Gegenbeispiel zu *Dieses Verb ist nicht Bestandteil der Alltagssprache*: "Hör auf zu schwallen!". In diesem Fall hat es jedoch eine idiomatische Bedeutung im Sinne von "daherreden" (vgl. Wortschwall).

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Ah! Wieder was dazugelernt. Diese Bedeutung von »schwallen« kannte ich bisher nicht.

Comment: Ich würde gerne +1 geben aber: "Wort-Schwall"???